# FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory (for Dogs and Cats code)

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Machine Learning and I'm following a Sentdex tutorial on Google Colab. It's supposed to be a ML program that distinguishes between cat and dog images. However, whenever I run my code, somethings wrong with my 'file or directory.'

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\atlgwc16\\PetImages/Dog'
```

I honestly don't know where Google Colab stores its files so I don't know where to put the folder of images.

Here is my full code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR = "C:\Users\atlgwc16\PetImages"
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
  path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category) 
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    plt.imshow(img_array, cmap = 'gray')
    plt.show()

    break
```

Comment: This is my first post so if I wrote this incorrectly please just inform me.

Comment: Try putting the pet images in the same folder as the python code and accessing it with DATADIR = "PetImages".

Comment: @Melanie Korrina A FileNotFound Error is a pretty general error. Could you please post your full code? This is nice for other Stack Overflow users who want to help answer your question, but cannot reproduce your error because they do not have your code.

Comment: @coltoneakins thank you for telling me that.. I changed it with my full code...

Comment: @MelanieKorrina Thank you for doing that. I answered your question below. When asking questions on Stack Overflow, the more details the better for future reference.

Comment: @coltoneakins Thank you so much for the help! Honestly can't thank you enough, I finally understand how to fix my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial being followed as referenced in the question:

https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-custom-data-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/

Since you are using Google Colab, you can upload the Kaggle dataset of dog and cat images to Google Drive. See the Google Colab Jupyter notebook provided by Google that explains how to do this:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA

You would then access files from your Google Drive (in this case, the training set after you upload it to Google Drive) much in the same way as accessing files locally on your computer.

This is the example provided in the link above:

```py
with open('/content/gdrive/My Drive/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('Hello Google Drive!')
!cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/foo.txt
```

So, since you are using Google Colab, you would need to adjust the code from the Sentdex tutorial to work better with the notebook you are creating. Google Colab uses Jupyter notebooks. Each cell in the notebook runs off of the same 'session'. So, if you import a Python module in one cell, it can be used in the next cells. It's magic like that.

It would look like this:

[CELL 1]

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

You will then give permission for Google Colab to access your Google Drive.

[CELL 2]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm

DATADIR = '/content/gdrive/My Drive/PetImages/'

#^See?#
# You would need to go to Google Drive and create the 'PetImages' folder at the top level of your Google Drive. You would upload the data set to the PetImages folder creating a 'Dog' subfolder and a 'Cat' subfolder.

CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
    for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it
        plt.show()  # display!

        break  # we just want one for now so break
    break  #...and one more!
```

After properly uploading the data set to Google Drive and using the special **google.colab** module, you should be able to easily access your training data. Google Colab is a cloud-based tool for creating Jupyter notebooks and running Python programs. So, while similar to running a Python program locally on your computer, it is *not* exactly the same. It would help to read through how Google Colab works more if you want to use it completely in the cloud--using GDrive to store files rather than your own computer. See the link I posted above from Google.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for my self and it works for me.
I use data set from my local drive such as a hard disk.
note: your dataset folder must be in the zip form.
first, follow the method with me and you will access your dataset from the local drive.I use google colab. first, create a Jupyter notebook in google Colab and run the below code step by step:

first step: run the below code in your notebook and upload your dataset from your hard drive or local drive

```
 from google.Colab import files
   uploaded = files.upload()
```

when the process is complete 100 percent and do the second step:

second step:
copy and run the below code, this step will unzip the dataset

```
import zipfile
import io

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(uploaded['DogVsCat.zip']), "r")
zf.extractall()
```

third step: run the code it will import all the required libraries

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

this will import all the required libraries for you.

fourth step:
specify the path for specifying the path do below steps:
fist: [check the image for more ease of your](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvOFr.png)

on the left corner folder icon click on the highlighted folder and you will see your unzip dataset  in my case my dataset is "DogVsCat",
note: there you will see two kinds of dataset zip and unzip, you copy the path of unzip data.
right click on it and copy the path from it and
run the below code:

```
 DIRECTORY ='/content/DogVsCats'
 CATEGORIES = ['cats', 'dogs']
```

note: please add your path in DIRECTORY(This directory is the path for me) path, not my path. and again run the code:
note: please add your own folder names in CATEGORIES not my folder names for more information see the picture:
[my dataset structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsC8H.png)
at the end create train data

5th step:

```
data = []
for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DIRECTORY, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_path = os.path.join(path, img)
        label = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        arr = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        new_arr = cv2.resize(arr, (60, 60))
        data.append([new_arr, label])
```

sixth step:

print the data:
run the below code to show you

```
data
```

seventh step: shuffle your data:

```
import random

random.shuffle(data)
```

eight-step:
specify features and labels for training the model

```
X = []
y = []

for features, label in data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

ninth-step: print features

```
X
```

tenth-step: print labels

```
 y
```

note I can not share all the code with you for the lack of time.

note: for more clearness check my code pictures:
[pic1-Of-My-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKe1m.png)
[pic2-of-my-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gnby.png)